# Can we reset phantom wallet so only we have access?

Tags: solana-program, phantom, phantom-wallet

I don't know how the hacker has access to my wallet because i checked and it was not connected to any scam website.

Now he just add funds to my wallet and drains me mostly on my sleeping time.

Is there a way i can reset my wallet so its only logged in on my pc only.

Its a burner and i also don't have the seed phase just have the private key. But this burner wallet is getting all the airdrops and they are worth alot.

Please

Answer (score 0):

No man, it isn't possible to do it, and if it was possible, the hacker who has access would have done it by now. Your wallets are defined by secret keys, so there is no log off from other devices kind of feature. You could try contacting the support, but I don't think they will be able to help you out as well. Sorry to hear that your wallet got compromised. Please practice utmost safety when u are using your wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear you are experiencing this. If you have not already please contact Phantom support via (Settings > Help & Support). They will advise of you if there are options for addressing this.